# JTable Respecting User Resizing of Columns - Until New Row Added

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` that is set to:

```
  theTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS);
```

When the user adjusts the width of a column, it respects that width until a new row is added to the table.  At that point, all the columns revert to their original widths.

In the debugger the `preferredWidth` of the column changes when the user adjust the width and the `minWidth` and `maxWidth` are set to appropriate values.  At some point after the new row is added the `preferredWidth` gets reverted back to the value that was used when the table was originally painted.

How can I have the table respect the user adjusted column widths after a new row is added?

Comment: After adding the row to the table model it gets changed so try to use `preferredWidth` after that also.

Answer (score 2):

The primary reasons `JTable` will reset the table columns is because it thinks the underlying structure of the table has changed.

This can be caused when the table model is changed (`JTable#setModel`) or the column model is changed (`JTable#setColumnModel`) or you call `tableStructureChanged` from within a `TableModel` that extends from `AbstractTableModel` or otherwise cause a `TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW` event to be triggered...

This is, of course, is all academic without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)